# SyslogAppender: Using a pattern not starting with square brackets overwrites the host name

Tags: java, log4j, rsyslog

I am using log4j and the SyslogAppender class to send messages to rsyslog running on the local Linux machine (called **orion**). I currently have the following pattern:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %m%n
```

Which produces this output:

```
Jun  5 16:16:09 orion [ERROR]: <My message here>
```

This doesn't show the source of the message and so I wanted to add that but unfortunately when I add anything before the square brackets, the host name disappears. eg.

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=TEST [%p] %m%n

Jun  5 16:22:41 TEST [ERROR]: <My message here>
```

It is not just literal text that causes this problem. For example, if I use the sample pattern from the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html), **"%-5p [%t]: %m%n"**, the hostname is also not there:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p [%t]: %m%n

Jun  5 16:25:34 ERROR [main]: <My message here>
```

Here is the simplest example I can come up with to demonstrate the problem using the patterns `aaa` and `[aaa]`:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=aaa
Jun  5 17:47:29 aaa

log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=[aaa]
Jun  5 17:48:24 orion [aaa]:
```

The documentation doesn't show that square brackets have any special meaning so I don't understand why this is happening. I'm also unclear on whether this problem is caused by the SyslogAppender class or rsyslog.

How do I keep the host name in the syslog message without wrapping the first item in square brackets?

Comment: Have you found a solution? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have not.

Comment: @guitar_freak I have, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to look at this with fresh eyes by looking at [the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.java.html) of the SyslogAppender class.

This subclass has an extra field called `header`:

```
  105       /**
  106        * If true, the appender will generate the HEADER (timestamp and host name)
  107        * part of the syslog packet.
  108        * @since 1.2.15
  109        */
  110     private boolean header = false;
```

Setting this value to true allows the hostname to show up.

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.layout.conversionPattern=TEST [%p] %m%n

May  9 16:50:14 orion TEST [ERROR] <my message here>
```

The documentation for `setHeader()` (confusingly mixed up with the documentation for `getHeader()`) has some extra information about the default value.

```
  460     /**
  461      * If true, the appender will generate the HEADER part (that is, timestamp and host name)
  462      * of the syslog packet.  Default value is false for compatibility with existing behavior,
  463      * however should be true unless there is a specific justification.
  464      * @since 1.2.15
  465     */
  466     public final boolean getHeader() {
  467         return header;
  468     }
  469   
  470       /**
  471        * Returns whether the appender produces the HEADER part (that is, timestamp and host name)
  472        * of the syslog packet.
  473        * @since 1.2.15
  474       */
  475     public final void setHeader(final boolean val) {
  476         header = val;
  477     }
```

The `header` value can either be set in Java code by calling `setHeader(true)` or by adding the following line to log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG_LOCAL1.header=true
```

Replace `SYSLOG_LOCAL1` with whatever you named this appender in your properties file.